# In R, Train/update model with multiple datasets

Tags: regex, r, neural-network, cluster-analysis, pattern-recognition

In R, I'm trying to train a neural network on multiple files. I have preformed the multinom function on a single dataset but I cannot find how to train my model with another dataset.

So I want to apply a model from a previous call to new data without re-estimating the model.

So first you build a model as in Sam Thomas's answer is explained.

```
#load libraries
library(nnet)
library(MASS)

#Define data
example(birthwt)

# Define training and test data
set.seed(321)
index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(bwt)), 130)
bwt_train <- bwt[index, ]
bwt_test <- bwt[-index, ] 

# Build model
bwt.mu <- multinom(low ~ ., data=bwt_train)
```

Then I have another similar dataset I want to train/update the earlier created model with. So I want to update the model with new data to improve my model.

```
# New data set (for example resampled bwt)
bwt2=sapply(bwt, sample)

head(bwt2,3)
     low age lwt race smoke ptd ht ui ftv
[1,]   1  31 115    3     1   1  0  0   2
[2,]   1  20  95    1     0   1  0  0   3
[3,]   2  25  95    2     0   1  0  1   1

# Define training and test data with new dataset
set.seed(321)
index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(bwt2)), 130)
bwt2_train <- bwt2[index, ]
bwt2_test <- bwt2[-index, ]
```

Now with this new dataset I want to optimze the model. I cannot merge the two datasets because the model should update over time when new data is available. This also because it is not preferable to recalculate everytime we have new data availble.

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from an example in `?nnet::multinom`

```
library(nnet)
library(MASS)
example(birthwt)

head(bwt, 2)
  low age lwt  race smoke   ptd    ht    ui ftv
1   0  19 182 black FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   0
2   0  33 155 other FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  2+

set.seed(321)
index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(bwt)), 130)
bwt_train <- bwt[index, ]
bwt_test <- bwt[-index, ] 

bwt.mu <- multinom(low ~ ., bwt_train)
(pred <- predict(bwt.mu, newdata=bwt_test))
 [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[39] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
```

Or if you want the probabilities

```
(pred <- predict(bwt.mu, newdata=bwt_test, type="probs"))
         1          5          6         16         19         23         24 
0.43672841 0.65881933 0.21958026 0.39061949 0.51970665 0.01627479 0.17210620 
        26         27         28         29         30         37         40 
0.06133368 0.31568117 0.05665126 0.26507476 0.37419673 0.18475433 0.14946268 
        44         46         47         51         56         58         60 
0.09670367 0.72178459 0.06541529 0.37448908 0.31883809 0.09532218 0.27515734 
        61         64         67         69         72         74         76 
0.27515734 0.09456443 0.16829037 0.62285841 0.12026718 0.47417711 0.09603950 
        78         87         94         99        100        106        114 
0.34588019 0.30327432 0.87688323 0.21177276 0.06576210 0.19741587 0.22418653 
       115        117        118        120        125        126        130 
0.14592195 0.19340994 0.14874536 0.30176632 0.09513698 0.08334515 0.03886775 
       133        134        139        140        145        147        148 
0.41216817 0.85046516 0.46344537 0.34219775 0.33673304 0.26894886 0.43778705 
       152        163        164        165        168        174        180 
0.19044485 0.27800125 0.17865143 0.86783149 0.25969355 0.60623964 0.34931986 
       182        183        185 
0.22944657 0.08066599 0.22863967
```

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for your answer. You explained how the multinom works on a normal dataset with one training dataset. My question is a step further. So now I have another training dataset to optimze my classifier. So how do I improve my earlier build model.

Comment: @AdamA3.  Thanks for the comment.  It may help to elaborate on what you mean by improving the model; a reproducible example is also helpful.  If you have a specific idea of what you want to do, that fits stackoverflow.  If you have questions of a more statistical nature, then crossvalidated would be more appropriate.